# How to track how many mails have been sent from each domain in Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am currently trying to configure a way to track the emails that i am sending through Amazon SES by using multiple domains. What i really want to achieve is to be able to track how many emails have been sent from each domain seperately. It is something i can achieve throught SES API ?I couldn't find any solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no AWS offered API for that. You can set up SES [delivery notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html). This pushes notification to SNS topic. You can then create a subscription to this SNS topic. This really opens up much more possibilities of what you can do to achieve your goal. The simplest approach could be just sending an email and processing it in your email client if you don't have many emails sending out from SES. More sophisticated approaches may involve setting up an HTTP endpoint and letting SNS send back HTTP(S) data, or utilizing AWS lambda and SQS, etc.

Comment: Ok. I was hopping that it could be done through SES API. Thank you !